# Logical difference between working on the second and third heap first versus first and second heap

Tags: c++, algorithm

A few days ago, I was trying to solve a CodeForces' question:

> There are three heaps of stones, say A, B and C.  We can remove 1 stone from A followed by 2 from B; or 1 from B followed by 2 from C.  Given the number of stones in each of the heaps, return the max number of stones that can be removed.  For e.g., in case of `3,4,5`, the max number of stones that can be removed is `9` - first, 2 from B and 4 from C, followed by 1 from A and 2 from B.

I wrote the code, wherein I remove multiples of 2 from B and singles from A followed by multiples of 2 from C and singles from B as below:

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(null);

    while(--n) {
        int a, b, c, ans=0;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;

        while(a>=1 && b>=2) {     //This one
            a--;
            b-=2;
            ans+=3;
        }

        while(b>=1 && c>=2) {     //That one
            b--;
            c-=2;
            ans+=3;
        }

        cout<<ans<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This breaks on the example `3,4,5` given above - my output is `6` instead of `9`.  Other solutions that passed the judge have the two loops commented above swapped.

While I understand the example on which it fails, I am unable to intuitively understand the difference between what is achieved by swapping the two loops - why is it necessary to work on heaps `B` and `C` first, before working on `A` and `B`?

Note: I have edited out other details from the question that are not actually required for this question.

Comment: It's basically just because of the 'direction' the question defined for the rule. Suppose A-B-C are left to right. So long that you have stones on A, it is possible to try to remove a stone, even thought it might fail with B having a single stone left. Same for B in regard to C. However, if you first remove all you can from A, and B is emptied, then even if C had 9 rocks, they can't be touched. Simply put: since 'stacks' are 'eaten' faster on the rightmost side, you avoid bottleneck by proceeding from right to left, whilst it is unsafe to proceed from left to right (e.g. 4-8-16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the values of the stones in `B`, every stone taken is equivalent to two stones from `C`, *but* every stone taken from `A` is equivalent to two stones from `B` and no stones from `C`.

So, to maximize the number of stones, you want to take stones first from `B`, then from `A`.

Comment: Well, I do not fully agree with the statement _...and no stones from C_.  I did have the second loop as well (wherein I worked on `B` and `C`).  It is just that I worked on `A` and `B` first, followed by `B` and `C`.

Comment: @J.Doe Each stone you take from `A` is essentially four stones you don't take from `C`, hence you can be left with stones in `C` if you take from `A` first.